# Choose data structure and algorithm for assigning books to category

Tags: c++, data-structures, project

I want to write following project:

Books in library are described as following: `author; title; label1, label2, label3...`

Book may have few labels. Sample data in txt file:

```
Herbert; Dune; sci-fi; desert;
Shakespeare; Hamlet; tragedy, baroque;
```

I want to display books by labels. For example:

```
desert:
Herbert; Dune;

sci-fi:
Herbert; Dune;

tragedy:
Shakespeare; Hamlet;

baroque:
Shakespeare; Hamlet;
```

Which data structure should I use to store books data? I don't want to get all labels and iterate over all books. I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: You may want to look into relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on more factors. For example, how much are you willing to trade space for time?

> I don't want to get all labels and iterate over all books. I'm open to any ideas.

If you want to focus on that look-up and make that as fast as possible (while allowing compromises on other operations, eg insertion) then the following might be an option.

You can keep a `std::map< label, std::vector<book> > m` that stores each book several times, once for each label. Then the look up is simply:

```
auto books = m["label1"]; // all books with label "label1"
```

You do not need to store copies of the books when you add a level of indirection and store indices or iterators to the container that stores the actual instances:

```
 std::vector<book> books;
 std::map< std::string, std::vector<unsigned>> m;
 for ( const auto& ind : m["label1"]) {
     book b = books[ind];
     // ...
 }
```

However, depending on the size of `books`, looking up books at random indices in the vector can be rather expensive while with the above this is avoided at the cost of storing each book multiple times.